# Backtracking Algorithm Sudoku using C

Tags: c, algorithm, backtracking

I am working on a sudoku exercise using the backtracking algorithm using C. It prints the gameboard with the first solution it finds, however it does not stop there and continues the recursion by removing the fields of the gameboard and creates a new solution. The problem is somewhere in the solve function. Here is my approach:

```
#include "sudoku.hpp"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>


int field[SIZE][SIZE];
int initial[SIZE][SIZE];


/* Initializes the sudoku array.
 * The field initial keeps the original start value for
 * figuring out if a value is fixed or can be changed. */
void init(int begin[SIZE][SIZE]) {
    memcpy(field, begin, SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(int));
    memcpy(initial, begin, SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(int));
}

/* Retrieves the solution. NEEDED FOR AUTO-TESTING PURPOSES. */
void getResult(int result[SIZE][SIZE]){
    memcpy(result, field, SIZE * SIZE * sizeof(int));
}

/* pretty prints the sudoku array */
void print() {
    int row, col;
    // print the first line
    printf("||");
    for (col = 0; col < SIZE - 1; col++) {
        if (col % SQRT_SIZE == SQRT_SIZE - 1) 
            printf("===++");
        else
            printf("===+");
    }
    printf("===||\n");
    // loop through all rows of the array
    for (row = 0; row < SIZE; row++) {
        // print the line with field values
        for (col = 0; col < SIZE; col++) {
            if (col % SQRT_SIZE == 0) 
                printf("|| ");
            else 
                printf("| ");
            if (field[row][col] == 0) 
                printf("  ");
            else
                printf("%d ", field[row][col]);
        }
        // print the separation line;
        // depending on the result of the modulo operation
        // print a single or double line
        printf("||\n||");
        if (row % SQRT_SIZE == SQRT_SIZE - 1) {
            for (col = 0; col < SIZE - 1; col++) {
                if (col % SQRT_SIZE == SQRT_SIZE - 1) 
                    printf("===++");
                else
                    printf("===+");
            }
            printf("===||\n");
        }
        else {
            for (col = 0; col < SIZE - 1; col++) {
                if (col % SQRT_SIZE == SQRT_SIZE - 1) 
                    printf("---++");
                else
                    printf("---+");
            }
            printf("---||\n");
        }
    }
}

/* Checks if the value is valid and can be set into the field.
 * The function returns false if the value is already present or
 * has been one of the initial values. */
int checkValueInField(int value, int row, int col) {
    int i, r, c;
    int squareRow;
    int squareCol;
    // checks for initial values
    if (initial[row][col] != 0) {
        if (initial[row][col] == value)
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;
    } 

    // check horizontally
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (field[row][i] == value) return 0;
    }

    // check vertically
    for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
        if (field[i][col] == value) return 0;
    }

    // check square
    squareRow = row / SQRT_SIZE;
    squareCol = col / SQRT_SIZE;
    for (r = squareRow * SQRT_SIZE; r < squareRow * SQRT_SIZE + SQRT_SIZE; r++) {
        for (c = squareCol * SQRT_SIZE; c < squareCol * SQRT_SIZE + SQRT_SIZE; c++) {
            if (field[r][c] == value) return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}

/* Set a value in the sudoku field if the field is empty.
 * The method returns false if the field contains a fixed number. */
int setValueInField(int value, int row, int col) {
   if (initial[row][col] == 0) {
       field[row][col] = value;
       return 1;
   }
   else if (initial[row][col] == value)
       return 1;
   return 0;
} 

/* Removes a value in the sudoku field if it doesn't contain an initial value.
 * The method returns false if the field contains a fixed number and cannot be
 * removed. */
int removeValueFromField(int row, int col) {
    if (initial[row][col] == 0) {
        field[row][col] = 0;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Returns the value in the field */
int getValueFromField(int row, int col) {
    return field[row][col];
}

/* Return true after a valid solution for the sudoku has been found. */
int solve(int row, int col) {
    print();
    bool isSet = false;
    if (row == 0 && col == 0) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) {
            if (checkValueInField(i, row, col) && getValueFromField(row, col) == 0) {
                isSet = setValueInField(i, row, col);
                if (isSet) {
                    solve(row, col);
                }
                if (row == SIZE - 1 && col == SIZE - 1) {
                    return 1;
                }
                else {
                    removeValueFromField(row, col);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (row == SIZE - 1 && col == SIZE - 1) {
        //Here is the solution, but then it continues after returning 1
        for (int r = 1; r <= SIZE; r++) {
            for (int c = 1; c <= SIZE; c++) {
                if (getValueFromField(r, c) != 0) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (row == SIZE - 1) {
        row = 0;
        col = col++;
    }
    else {
        row = row++;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= SIZE; i++) {
        if (checkValueInField(i, row, col) == 1) {
            isSet = setValueInField(i, row, col);
            solve(row, col);
            if (row == SIZE - 1 && col == SIZE == -1) {
                return 1;
            }
            else {
                    removeValueFromField(row, col);
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

This is my header file:

```
#ifndef _SUDOKU_H_
#define _SUDOKU_H_

#define SIZE 9
#define SQRT_SIZE 3

void init(int begin[SIZE][SIZE]);
void getResult(int result[SIZE][SIZE]);
void print();
int checkValueInField(int value, int row, int col);
int setValueInField(int value, int row, int col);
int removeValueFromField(int row, int col);
int getValueFromField(int row, int col);
int solve(int row, int col);
```

This is the initial gameboard and its solution:

```
int initial[SIZE][SIZE] = {
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 5, 0},
        {0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 0},
        {0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 3, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0},
        {4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 9},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 3},
        {2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    };
    int expected[SIZE][SIZE] = {
        {3, 1, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 5, 6},
        {5, 9, 7, 3, 2, 6, 4, 8, 1},
        {8, 6, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 9, 7},
        {7, 4, 5, 6, 1, 8, 9, 3, 2},
        {9, 3, 8, 7, 4, 2, 1, 6, 5},
        {6, 2, 1, 5, 9, 3, 8, 7, 4},
        {4, 7, 3, 2, 8, 5, 6, 1, 9},
        {1, 8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 5, 2, 3},
        {2, 5, 6, 9, 3, 1, 7, 4, 8},
    };
```

This is my testcase:

```
TEST_CASE("Test2", "Sudoku")
{
    int result = 0;
    int actual[SIZE][SIZE];
    int initial[SIZE][SIZE] = {
        {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 5, 0},
        {0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 8, 0},
        {0, 6, 0, 1, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 9, 3, 0},
        {0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0},
        {0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0},
        {4, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 9},
        {0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 5, 0, 3},
        {2, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0},
    };
    int expected[SIZE][SIZE] = {
        {3, 1, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 5, 6},
        {5, 9, 7, 3, 2, 6, 4, 8, 1},
        {8, 6, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3, 9, 7},
        {7, 4, 5, 6, 1, 8, 9, 3, 2},
        {9, 3, 8, 7, 4, 2, 1, 6, 5},
        {6, 2, 1, 5, 9, 3, 8, 7, 4},
        {4, 7, 3, 2, 8, 5, 6, 1, 9},
        {1, 8, 9, 4, 6, 7, 5, 2, 3},
        {2, 5, 6, 9, 3, 1, 7, 4, 8},
    };
    init(initial);
    result = solve(0,0);
    getResult(actual);
    INFO("Test Case: valid Sudoku board failed.");
    REQUIRE(memcmp(actual, expected, sizeof(initial)) == 0);
    INFO("Test Case: return value not correct.");
    REQUIRE(result == 1);
}
```

Comment: In `solve`, you recurse using `solve(row, col);` and then do absolutely *nothing* with the result. One of the *most* common mistakes of beginners using recursion is failing to reap recursed results from the recursed call(s). This is that. There are *hundreds* of duplicates on this site with the same problem, but they're difficult to track down because the vernacular, title, etc., of the posts are so divergent they often share little in common besides words like "recursion don't work"

Comment: What should I do with the result then?

Comment: What does the result represent? It represents something, right? Doesn't it represent that that path, from that jump-in point of recursion, somehow led to a solution? If that's the case, that's the point where you back out entirely *without* undoing your entrance state change because you'd be removing your just-discovered solution. All the recursed returns should take that same action, and you'll finally emerge with the top-most `solve` returning "solved", and the puzzle itself completed.

Comment: @AllanWind was kinda hoping the OP would notice that :-P

Comment: @WhozCraig Deleted my comment.  You still have a chance :-)

Comment: @AllanWind They may get it. Should. It becomes obvious that's a thing to address once they start properly relying on it.

Comment: I am still struggling, although you gave me these hints.
The result represents the path from the jump-in point of the recursion, but how does this information lead to my solution? How can I back out of the recursion?

Comment: I introduced a new variable

int res = -1;

then I assigned it to solve

res = solve(row, col);

and tried to terminate it when res does not equal zero 

if(res == 0){
   removeFromField(row, col);
}else{
 return 1;
}  


It sill doesn't work. I appreciate any further help

Comment: @AllanWind any more hints, please?

Comment: @linuxman You want to update your question with the above change (instead of a comment).  "doesn't work" is way too vague description of the current state of question.  As you get more precise and detailed, it will help you troubleshoot. An effective way to attract an  audience is make it really easy to paste your code and run (see [mre]).    When I look at your question is has 1 program and 4 snippets.  If you make that self-contained single program with a test it's easier to help you.

Comment: https://github.com/BostonBrooks/Spaghetti_Graveyard/blob/master/sudoku.c